# SCHTASKS Invalid Syntax in C# but working in CMD

Tags: c#, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I've got a command I'm trying to run through C# to get a list of tasks in CSV format from a bunch of computers.

To do this, I am using the SCHTASKS command with command redirection to a CSV. So I wrote this code in C# to do this for me:

```
        string commandGetStatus = "schtasks";
        string argumentsGetStatus = "/s:" + CompName +
                " /fo:csv" +
                " > \"" + @"\\BIG\OL\UNC\PATH\"+CompName+".csv" + "\"";

        getLatestTaskStatus.StartInfo.FileName = commandGetStatus;
        getLatestTaskStatus.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentsGetStatus;
        getLatestTaskStatus.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        getLatestTaskStatus.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        getLatestTaskStatus.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        getLatestTaskStatus.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        getLatestTaskStatus.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        getLatestTaskStatus.Start();
```

It returns the output:

```
        ERROR: Invalid syntax.

        Type "SCHTASKS /?" for usage.
```

So I used `StartInfo.FileName + " " + StartInfo.Arguments` to print out the exact command that should be being executed. From there, I copy and pasted the command into CMD. Where it worked without a problem. This was the command + args:

```
        schtasks /s:COMPUTERNAME /fo:csv > "\\BIG\OL\UNC\PATH\COMPUTERNAME.csv"
```

I'm not sure what the problem is at this point.

---

**My Solution**

Luaan was absolutely correct about the problem. The command prompt redirection operator,`>`, is not available without using Command Prompt. Fortunately, the solution was quote simple and easy to implement. I reduced the argument variable to:

`"/s:" + CompName + " /fo:csv"`

And with standard output being redirected, I simply used:

```
            string output = process.StandardOuptut.ReadToEnd();
            File.WriteAllText(@"\\UNC\File\Path\" + myfile + ".csv", output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly disabled `UseShellExecute` - `>` is a shell operator, not something inherent to processes. It definitely isn't *an argument*. You need to read the output and write it out manually :)

Comment: Ah. Well, that would probably be the issue then :)
Will accept when it allows me.